# Tutorial for OAuth in App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, oauth

I know the basics of App Engine and Python. I am right now trying to write a web app to ask the user to log in with OAuth and then display their email address. Do you know any tutorial that teaches OAuth for complete OAuth noobs?

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend the [oauth2client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/OAuth2) documentation. In particular, there's a nice bit of [sample code](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/OAuth2#OAuth2Decorator) for conveniently using it from App Engine.